# How do I throw the ball from the Wildcat or similar formations with run/pass options?

Tags: madden-11

In Madden 11, how do you throw the ball from run/pass option formations?

Comment: See my updated answer, it contains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they're any Run/Pass options. It's either pass or run. If people aren't paying attention you can put your QB in (instead of a running back) and throw with him. They'll see WildCat on the play call screen, but its more like a Tim Tebow/Florida Gators offense.

**EDIT**:

Okay so I found what you want! It's in the Denver Broncos playbook. The formation is called **Shotgun Bronco Heavy**. It is in the shotgun formation. You'll have to sub Tim Tebow in as your **2nd string** QB to have him in this formation. You can run, pass, and QB sneak.

<strike>The best part about this formation is that on the playcall screen, it **doesn't show up as WILDCAT**, it just says 1 RB 1 WR 3 TE.</strike> This is no longer true after a recent update to Madden 11. It now shows up as a Wildcat formation in Madden 11/12.

Comment: Can't your running back throw it?

Comment: @mmyers: Yes but you don't get to decide during the play. You must decide if you want to run it, or if you want to pass it. The OP wants to be able to do either using the same play.

Comment: Bronco Heavy isn't a Wildcat formation: that's when someone other than the QB takes the snap. None of those plays are option plays, either, they're all normal plays.

Comment: @Dave: It's treated as a Wildcat in that you can't audible your plays and it even shows up as Wildcat to your opponent online.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but doesn't your answer say that it doesn't show up as Wildcat to your opponents?

Comment: @Dave: It does. :) And that was true back when I wrote that answer, however after a title update to Madden (and in Madden 12) it shows up as Wildcat.

Comment: In that case, it would be great if you updated your answer accordingly; we want to keep answers up-to-date whenever we can. The OP may have moved on, but I know some people are still playing 11.

Comment: @Dave: Done and done!

Answer (score 0):

Madden doesn't have true option plays like NCAA does: these are really trick plays that involve passes, like the Lions' HB Pass out of the I.

Some teams, like the Eagles, have no pass options from the Wildcat. The only plays they offer are run plays. (The read option in Cleveland's Flash package is a run play: the "option" is keeping or handing off, based on your key, which is usually the backside DE or LB.)

Other teams, like the Dolphins, have plays like Jet Sweep Pass. This is basically the same as the HB Pass above: someone other than the QB acts like a QB. You throw to receivers the same way you throw to receivers normally, by pressing the appropriate buttons, and you can "scramble" the same way you scramble with a QB.